# Invalid geometry value

Tags: geodjango

I defined a PointField in one of my models and included it in the ModelAdmin. The admin is showing properly a map to select the point, but once I select it and save it raises a validation error **Invalid geometry value**.

In the console I can see the following error:

```
Error creating geometry from value 'SRID=4.326;POINT(4.39453125 7.470703125)' (String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB.)
```

As for I've read, I think (not sure) that is "*SRID=4.326;*" what should not be there. Any idea of why django is prefixing it or what is missing?

The field definition in the model (I tried removing the srid attribute):

```
coords = models.PointField(_('Coordinates'), null=True, blank=True, srid=4326)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `SRID` you have a point where there should not be one: `4.326` will not be recognized as valid srid.

So instead of

```
'SRID=4.326;POINT(4.39453125 7.470703125)'
```

use

```
'SRID=4326;POINT(4.39453125 7.470703125)'
```